# Keep User Instance Signed-in, Signing back in, if signed out

Tags: powershell, automation, scheduled-tasks, auto-login, autologon

We have a requirement to have an executable running on a specific user's profile to enable our reports to run for some 3rd party software we use.

It's fine if the session is 'disconnected'.

Auto-boot won't work, as this user account keeps being 'signed out' by our software developers, when they finish their work - we've told them to stop signing out.

I was thinking a PowerShell script could be used to query if X user was signed in - running every 15 minutes - signing them in, should their session have been 'signed out'.

Any ideas..?

(edit 1, 15/05/2023)
I managed to use NSSM and got the .BAT to run as a service, however, the CSV reports produced came through blank.
I suspect it's due to the .exe being run requiring additional commands to pull the correct data.
I'm going to see if I can get NSSM's arguments to process those of the BAT file - script below.

```
echo off
set WRKDRV=C:
set WRKDIR="C:\Program Files\Principal Systems\LIVE\In-DEX\5.0\wrk"
%WRKDRV%
cd %WRKDIR%
call "C:\Progress\OpenEdge\bin\prowin.task.scheduler.exe" -basekey "INI" -ininame "..\bin\in-dex.ini" -pf "..\bin\in-dex.pf" -rr -p lib/tasks.w -param "START;1"
exit
exit
```

Comment: I think this sounds like a case for autologin honestly. Sounds like you have a dedicated account that all the developers share on a machine and when sign out of it when they are done instead of disconnecting via RDP or perhaps at the console as well. You can force auto log back in with auto login configuration with either a domain or a local user Windows account. This is possible, but you may need to clarify if something like that would suffice, tag me back with an `@` sign and then type my name, then the comment and I'll be on the lookout to add an answer if you tell me that will suffice.

Comment: Also, system services are nice but I've seen more daemon type processes that need to run as the logged on/interactive user for proper reporting, etc. so not sure what the case is in this instance, but I've seen that solution suffice sometimes and sometimes not depending on the constraints, other detail, and context for your specific needs with however the executable works and what it's doing, etc.

Comment: You can enable a group policy that disables the ability to log out of a user. This policy would apply to all users.  It sounds like you need a dedicated machine for this user profile.  This policy should allow you to switch users.  It won't prevent the machine from being locked.

Comment: Yep, I've done all that from GPO as well, restrict LOGOFF option, restrict fast user switching, restrict use of the lock screen per key restrictions, autologin with forced log back in if logged off, etc. All that totally possible with script, policy, and/or any combination as such within a group policy. In any event, further clarification is needed otherwise any answer is a guess for what works for your need and environment.

Answer (score 1):

Idea : Run the program or PowerShell script as a system service.
This will make it independent from any active user session.

The tool to use would be
[SrvStart](https://github.com/rozanski/srvstart)
which will wrap it so it can work as a system service.
To create the service, use the Microsoft
[sc.exe create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create).
The service can be set to run automatically at boot under the
specified user account.

You will find an old tutorial for doing this in the article
[How to Run Any Program as a Background Service in Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/).
Although some details have changed since it was written, its essence
is still correct.

(Note : I can't guarantee that it will work successfully
for your specific PowerShell script.)